# mysql query for website visiter count

Tags: mysql, sql, hit-count

I have a table to store website visiter count bellow

```
id   date          ip            
-----------------------------
1    1-1-2012     195.165.1.2
2    1-1-2012     195.165.1.3
3    12-2-2012    195.165.1.8
```

and i want a mysql query for get count of each month of current year

Answer (score 3):

seeing your `DATE` column, i assumed that you save dates as `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c-%e-%Y')) `monthName`, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    tableName
WHERE   YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c-%e-%Y')) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c-%e-%Y'))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/347fa/8)

OTHER SOURCEs

- [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [YEAR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)
- [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)
- [MONTHNAME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

Answer (score 0):

```
"select month(date),count(distinct ip) from visitors where date>='$y-01-01' and date<'$y-12-31' group by 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT YEAR(date) YEAR,MONTHNAME(date) MONTH,count(id) TOTAL 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY YEAR(date),MONTH(date)

THE QUERY IS LIKE THIS BECAUSE DIFFERENT PERSONS FROM SAME IP MAY VISIT